# Do I need a 90 degree elbow on this intake and would I need to cement it on?

Tags: plumbing, hvac, pvc

There are two pvc intake/exhaust pipes on the outside of my house, and both of them don’t have an elbow on them.
Is it bad to not have an elbow on the top of the pipe and what type of damage can occur if it water gets into the hvac system?
If i have to install it, would pvc cement be the proper adherence method. They seem to be hvac exhaust pipes
[image]

Comment: It looks like they both had caps of some sort ??

Answer (score 1):

Almost assuredly the taller one originally had a 180 elbow on it and is the air intake - the lower one probably had a 90 elbow facing down and would be the exhaust.  It's visually obvious that they used to have elbows on them.  Yep, PVC glue would be best to attach the elbows.  But if they've come off, then likely they were originally just press-fit into place and there's a good chance your intake elbow and pipe are just pressed into place as well and are held by friction alone.

Comment: You'd also probably want to include some sort of critter guard to keep birds/rodents/bugs from getting in.

Comment: When I had a high efficiency furnace installed, I was told to not put any kind of screening over those openings.

Comment: Might be worth painting the pipe too, for some UV protection.